# Does $\sum^\infty_{n=3}\frac {\ln^2(n)}{n^{3/2}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find a way to decide if this sum converges or diverges, I'm trying to use the integral test and bound the integrand or use the limit comparison test, but I am not finding a good function to compare my integrand with at infinity. 
 I would appreciate any help or tips in how to find a function that behaves like $\frac {\ln^2(x)}{x^{3/2}}$ at $x\to \infty$ that I can use it for limit comparison test. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^{3/2}}}{\frac1{n^{5/4}}}=0$.

Comment: Thanks alot for the hint, may I ask like what led you to compare the function with $\frac {1}{n^{5/4}}$? Is it usually a good idea to look for bounds near $\frac {1}{n}$?

Comment: I looked for a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^\alpha}$ with $1<\alpha<\frac32$ and so I took the arithmetic mean between $1$ and $\frac32$, which is $\frac54$.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation, I will note that trick!

Answer (score 2):

[Integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) for the convergence. The integral is pretty doable
$$\int_3^{\infty } \frac{\log ^2(x)}{x^{3/2}} \, dx=\lim_{M\to\infty}\left[-\frac{2 \left(\log ^2(x)+4 \log (x)+8\right)}{\sqrt{x}}\right]_3^M=\frac{2 \left(8+\log ^2(3)+\log (81)\right)}{\sqrt{3}}$$
As the integral converges, the series converges as well.